# Amoebic sea and you

Tags: aliens, environment, space-colonization

In the hit Discovery channel docufiction Alien Planet, based on the book Expedition by Wayne Barlow, a planet called Darwin iv is explored. One of it's most interesting environments is the amoebic sea. Instead of water oceans, there's this massive super organism of microbes forming a thick gelatinous layer over what remains of the sea.

It's mostly like a desert, having little rain but very sudden wind storms. More than a few organisms come to nibble on this plentiful food source and the sea occasionally reaches out to eat them in some places. The most notable residents are the gigantic sea striders, creatures the size of sky scrapers that walk across the surface, biting into it with mouths on their feet.
My question is how do you see a human colony interacting with a similar environment/ organism? Let's assume they're stranded on this planet so they can't just ignore it. Do you see it as being of any real use to them or just a big inconvenience?

https://speculativeevolution.fandom.com/wiki/Amoebic_Sea

Comment: If you don't have any ideas, have you heard of anyone else whose been working with this in fiction?

Comment: this almost seems like third party material

Comment: @Topcode this argument comes up a lot, and it seldom holds much water. All the OP would need to do is to file off the serial numbers and drop a few links and ask about a hypothetical and totally unrelated world involving an ocean-scale biofilm and the question would suddenly become valid. It doesn't involve or require deep knowledge and understanding of somebody else's complex backstory and setting, and any useful answers need not reference those. Conversely, "_Why would/did Harry Potter do this_" seems like a good example of a third party universe question.

Comment: That said, this _is_ an extremely broad question which doesn't seem like a good fit for the site as-is. It doesn't obviously have right or wrong answers, for example, and invites stories in response.

Answer (score 3):

#### After a few missteps initially, we will set up an industrial process to destroy it for profit.

Call me jaded, but humanities interaction with resources will follow a millenia old pattern and would be fairly predictable:

- The first few people to get too close without protection will be consumed by the sea.
- Humans will develop whatever armour or weapons they need to not be consumed and take parts of it for study.
- We'll figure out when sliced and cooked and that it tastes like a steak, or that it can be dried and turned into a building material, or dried up and burnt as fuel, etc. Basically well figure out a way to profit from it.
- All the natural sea will be comsumed, eventually we'll need to start farming it in vats because we were too greedy.